# SageFormIntegration.ProcessRequest - Object Reference not set - .NET

Tags: opayo

I'm getting and object reference not set error on the following code.

```
Line 28:     public IFormPayment ProcessRequest(IFormPayment formPayment)
Line 29:     {
Line 30:         RequestQueryString = BuildQueryString(ConvertSagePayMessageToNameValueCollection(ProtocolMessage.FORM_PAYMENT, typeof(IFormPayment), formPayment,SagePaySettings.ProtocolVersion));
Line 31: 
Line 32:         formPayment.Crypt = Cryptography.EncryptAndEncode(RequestQueryString, SagePaySettings.EncryptionPassword);
```

Stack Trace

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
SagePay.IntegrationKit.SagePayIntegration.GetPropertyTextValue(Object request, String propertyName) in C:\dev\dotnet\VspDotNetKitAPI\SagePayIntegration.cs:93
SagePay.IntegrationKit.SagePayIntegration.ConvertSagePayMessageToNameValueCollection(ProtocolMessage protocolMessage, Type type, IMessage message, ProtocolVersion protocolVersion) in C:\dev\dotnet\VspDotNetKitAPI\SagePayIntegration.cs:155
SagePayFormIntegration.ProcessRequest(IFormPayment formPayment) in c:\SagePayKit\App_Code\SagePay\SagePayFormIntegration.cs:30
Form_Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\SagePayKit\Lockings\Default.aspx.cs:36
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +70
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3177
```

Probably something really obvious I am missing here but I've been looking at it for some time and comparing it to the integration kits version, which works fine, and connect see where I am going wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I have solved this. Some of the shipping details were sent as null instead of empty strings.

Comment: A bit old, but still valid. I had the same issue and it's bloody difficult to figure out what causes it. Thanks to undercommenting and non-documenting the assembly, not an awful lot can be inferred. Cheers for the pointer @baked.